# Problem finding a face center of a mirrored object using a ray_cast

Tags: python, faces, mirror

I want to find a face center of a face I'm clicking on using the `.ray_cast` method. Since this method returns a face index, I thought I'll just use it to get the center coordinate from `obj.data.polygons[face_index].center`.

However when I have an object with a `Mirror` modifier with a `Bisect` option turned on, `.ray_cast` returns a face index of the original, not mirrored face even though I'm iterating on evaluated depsgraph. Here in this gif the printed face index is the same for both faces of the `Mirror w/ Bisect` object while two other objects return different proper values:

[image]

- can I somehow get the correct face index?
- maybe there's a different way of getting a face center coordinate that'd work on this object?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/vmYEnPaU)'s a slightly modified version of the default Blender raycast template that prints out a face index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I used [scene ray cast](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.ray_cast) instead. It worked faster than ray casting through objects and was returning correct normals/faces.